# How does Find Content really work?

Tags: content

I've added a Related Content field to Cases, and this allows attaching of content. Three buttons show up in the Related Content field: Find Content, Search All, and Deliver Content. The last one, Deliver Content, seems to be a way to upload local content and send it. The second one, Search All, seems to be a search of all accessible existing library content.

The first one, Find Content, seems to generate a list of `content relevant to Case: <number>`. How is this relevancy determined?